# Quickbooks api not returning data

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Hello guys I'm following this tutorial '[QuickBooks OAuth – PHP Example](https://developer.intuit.com/hub/blog/2014/02/25/quickbooks-oauth-php-example)' to set up the api and get the data from the quickbooks. I have successfully setup the api but the problem that I'm facing now is that I'm unable to get the data from the quick books. It always returns me null even though their is alot of data present over there

Here is the code to what I'm doing.

**config.php**

```
<?php
  // setting up session
  /* note: This is not a secure way to store oAuth tokens. You should use a secure
  *     data sore. We use this for simplicity in this example.
  */
  // session_save_path('./abc/temp');
  session_save_path('./abc/temp');
  session_start();

  echo "<h4>If you see a Session warning above you need to run the command: 'chmod 777 temp' in the terminal on the code page. </h4>";

  define('OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY', 'some key');
  define('OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET', 'some key');


  if(strlen(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY) < 5 OR strlen(OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET) < 5 ){
    echo "<h3>Set the consumer key and secret in the config.php file before you run this example</h3>";
  }


?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
  require_once("./config.php");
?>

<html>
<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>My Connect Page</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appcenter.intuit.com/Content/IA/intuit.ipp.anywhere.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Runnable uses dynamic URLs so we need to detect our current //
    // URL to set the grantUrl value   ########################### //
    /*######*/ var parser = document.createElement('a');/*#########*/
    /*######*/parser.href = document.url;/*########################*/
    // end runnable specific code snipit ##########################//
    intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup({
        menuProxy: '',
        grantUrl: 'http://'+parser.hostname+'/QuickbooksTest/oauth.php?start=t' 
        // outside runnable you can point directly to the oauth.php page
    });
  </script>
</head>

</head>
<body>

<?php
require_once('./v3-php-sdk-2.3.0/config.php');  // Default V3 PHP SDK (v2.0.1) from IPP
require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'Core/ServiceContext.php');
require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'DataService/DataService.php');
require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'PlatformService/PlatformService.php');
require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'Utility/Configuration/ConfigurationManager.php');

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

// print connect to QuickBooks button to the page
echo "<ipp:connectToIntuit></ipp:connectToIntuit><br />";

// After the oauth process the oauth token and secret 
// are storred in session variables. 
if(!isset($_SESSION['token'])){
  echo "<h3>You are not currently authenticated</h3>";
} else {
  $token = unserialize($_SESSION['token']);
  $requestValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(
  $token['oauth_token'], $token['oauth_token_secret'], OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET);
  $realmId = $_SESSION['realmId'];

  // uncomment any of these to see more information 
  //echo "realmId: $realmId <br />";
  //echo "oauth token: ". $token['oauth_token'] . "<br />";
  //echo "oauth secret: ". $token['oauth_token'] . "<br />";
  /*echo "<pre><h2>Session Variables</h2>";
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    echo "</pre>"; */

  $serviceType = $_SESSION['dataSource'];
  $serviceContext = new ServiceContext($realmId, $serviceType, $requestValidator);

  $dataService = new DataService($serviceContext);

  // $startPosition = 1;
  // $maxResults = 10;
  // $allCustomers = $dataService->FindAll('Customer', $startPosition, $maxResults);
  $allCustomers = $dataService->Query("SELECT * FROM Customer");
  echo "<pre><h2>Customers List</h2>";
  var_dump($allCustomers);
  echo "</pre>";

}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATED INDEx**

```
<?php
  require_once("./config.php");
?>

<html>
<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>My Connect Page</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appcenter.intuit.com/Content/IA/intuit.ipp.anywhere.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Runnable uses dynamic URLs so we need to detect our current //
    // URL to set the grantUrl value   ########################### //
    /*######*/ var parser = document.createElement('a');/*#########*/
    /*######*/parser.href = document.url;/*########################*/
    // end runnable specific code snipit ##########################//
    intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup({
        menuProxy: '',
        grantUrl: 'http://'+parser.hostname+'/testProject/oauth.php?start=t' 
        // outside runnable you can point directly to the oauth.php page
    });
  </script>
</head>

</head>
<body>

<intuit>
  <ipp>
    <logger>       
      <!-- To enable/disable Request and Response log-->
      <requestLog enableRequestResponseLogging="true" requestResponseLoggingDirectory="C:\IdsLogs" />    
    </logger>
  </ipp>
</intuit>


<?php
require_once('./v3-php-sdk-2.3.0/config.php');  // Default V3 PHP SDK (v2.0.1) from IPP
require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'Core/ServiceContext.php');
require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'DataService/DataService.php');
require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'PlatformService/PlatformService.php');
require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'Utility/Configuration/ConfigurationManager.php');
require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'QueryFilter/QueryMessage.php');

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

// print connect to QuickBooks button to the page
echo "<ipp:connectToIntuit></ipp:connectToIntuit><br />";

// After the oauth process the oauth token and secret 
// are storred in session variables. 
if(!isset($_SESSION['token'])){
  echo "<h3>You are not currently authenticated</h3>";
} else {
  $token = unserialize($_SESSION['token']);
  $requestValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(
  $token['oauth_token'], $token['oauth_token_secret'], OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET);
  $realmId = $_SESSION['realmId'];


  error_log($realmId);  
  // uncomment any of these to see more information 
  //echo "realmId: $realmId <br />";
  //echo "oauth token: ". $token['oauth_token'] . "<br />";
  //echo "oauth secret: ". $token['oauth_token'] . "<br />";
  /*echo "<pre><h2>Session Variables</h2>";
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    echo "</pre>"; */


  // error_log("Value in dataSource session is: " . $_SESSION['dataSource']);
  // $serviceType = $_SESSION['dataSource']; //5:15 PM
  $serviceType = IntuitServicesType::QBO; //5:16 PM
  $serviceContext = new ServiceContext($realmId, $serviceType, $requestValidator);

  $dataService = new DataService($serviceContext);

  // $startPosition = 1;
  // $maxResults = 10;
  // $allCustomers = $dataService->FindAll('Customer', $startPosition, $maxResults);
  // $allCustomers = $dataService->Query("SELECT * FROM Customer");
  $allCustomers = $dataService->FindAll('Customer');

  // $oneQuery = new QueryMessage();
  // $oneQuery->sql = "SELECT";
  // $oneQuery->entity = "Customer";
  // $oneQuery->orderByClause = "FamilyName";

  // Run a query
  // $queryString = $oneQuery->getString();
  // $allCustomers = $dataService->Query($queryString);

  // $ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");
  // $fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

  // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
  // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

  // curl_exec($ch);
  // curl_close($ch);
  // fclose($fp);



  echo "<pre><h2>Customers List</h2>";
  var_dump($allCustomers);
  echo "</pre>";

}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

***APP.CONFIG*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <intuit>
    <ipp>
      <!--Json serialization not supported in PHP SDK v2.0.0 -->
      <message>
        <request serializationFormat="Xml" compressionFormat="None"/>
        <response serializationFormat="Xml" compressionFormat="None"/>
      </message>
      <service>
        <baseUrl qbd="https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/" qbo="https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/" ipp="https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/" />
      </service>
      <logger>
        <!-- To enable/disable Request and Response log-->
        <requestLog enableRequestResponseLogging="true" requestResponseLoggingDirectory="./IdsLogs" />
      </logger>
    </ipp>
  </intuit>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you enabled logging? What does the logging show? Have you actually clicked the "Connect to QuickBooks" button and connected to QuickBooks?

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. yes I have connected to the quickboks but I do not know how to enable logging

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. can you please guide how can I enable logging ?

Comment: I would start with the documentation: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0500_developer_kits/0209_php/php_sdk_for_quickbooks_v3/0002_configuration

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. where should I put it. should I put it in the config file

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. I have placed the logging code in `index.php` file from but no file or folder has been crreated.

Here is the code that I'm using for logging and correct me if I'm wrong.


`<intuit>
  <ipp>
    <logger>       
      <!-- To enable/disable Request and Response log-->
      <requestLog enableRequestResponseLogging="true" requestResponseLoggingDirectory="C:\IdsLogs" />    
    </logger>
  </ipp>
</intuit>`

Comment: Do you actually have a file named `C:\IdsLogs`?  Why don't you update your code so that we can actually see what you're tried so far? Did you read the documentation on the page I linked above?

Comment: What makes you assume that a folder will be created?

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. this thing makes me belief that folder or a file will be created. `requestResponseLoggingDirectory="C:\IdsLogs"`

Comment: A file might be created. That in no way implies that a folder will be created. Does the folder exist?

Comment: Did you update your post with your latest code and configuration?

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. added the updated code

Comment: The configuration stuff needs to go in your config file, not in your PHP script...

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. the configration file is also a php script. What difference will it make ?

Comment: No, it's not. Go look at the actual example included in the download. It's named `App.config` and it's an XML file. You can't just randomly throw stuff in random made-up HTML tags in your PHP script and expect things to work...

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. sorry for the late reply. I was kind of sick due to which I was not able to reply and  yeah you are right. My bad but now I have placed all the logging code in the app.config file and removed it from the index file now it should have made a file or something which would tell me that yeah logging is working.  Please tell me what is it that I'm doing wrong. I can't see the logging information